# Is BizTalk 2006 supported in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, biztalk

What I've googled so far is that the upcoming BizTalk 2009 R2 will be supported in VS 2010.  Nothing is said however regarding support for the current BizTalk 2006 R2 version.

Anyone knows whether BizTalk 2006 is supported in Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: anyone has info on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey user316221, here is a pretty good summary of the different versions of BizTalk and the required version of Visual Studio to develop for them. It's off a Microsoft employee's blog, so it should be legit:

http://blogs.msdn.com/amantaras/archive/2010/02/18/visual-studio-versions-used-by-each-release-of-biztalk.aspx

In short, the answer is no. BizTalk 2006 development is officially done with Visual Studio 2005. Visual Studio 2010 will be used for BizTalk 2010 development (previously named BizTalk 2009 R2).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the wording in [this recent ZDNet article](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=5656), it doesn't sound like it.

> BizTalk 2010 is a “minor” update that adds support for Visual Studio 2010

Judging by the term "adds", I would imagine that previous versions are not supported.